# Execution of shell script in /usr/local/bin/ fails

Tags: shell, cordova, terminal, applescript, bin

I try to execute the following shell command via applescript for fetching the cordova version:

```
do shell script "cd /usr/local/bin/; cordova -v;"
```

If I use the same command in terminal it works, in AppleScript I get the error:

> sh: cordova: command not found

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of tests, if figured out the solution:

do shell script "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; cordova -v;"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cordova -v"
```

**Edit:**

It seems that the "file" is a symbolic link.
This code resolves the alias

```
set symLink to "/usr/local/bin/cordova"
tell application "System Events" to set cordova to POSIX path of (get alias symLink)
do shell script cordova & " -v"
```

Comment: I tried that already, it gives me the error: No such file or directory. Because of that I changed the directory.

Comment: If that fails then the path isn't valid

Comment: In Finder type ⇧⌘G and then `/usr/local/bin`. Is the file there?